# Pressing button resets the page

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I know this is something really simple, but I can't figure out to keep the page from jumping to the top when a button is pressed. I'm using some jquery to make pictures fade in and out when a button is pressed, but it makes the page jump up to the top!

I'm also using twitter bootstrap

Please view the source here and see if you can find what's wrong I'd really appreciate it!

edit: forgot the source!!!

http://schechterbusiness.info/

Comment: Did you forget to add the source?

Comment: where is the source?  Is your button in a form?

Comment: There's no link.  Also, you really need to give us something more specific that a link and a request to view the source.  We aren't contractors, we are here to answer specific questions.

Comment: sorry about forgetting the source! no it's not in a form, @ChrisHerbert it's a really simple problem, I can't really get anymore specific. Instead of jumping to the top of the page (like when you use <a href="#">) I don't want to the page to move.

Comment: @eric.itzhak where does that go in the code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- obviously `click me!` buttons doesn't work and brings you to top as there is no events for them
- assign `id="fryLink"`, `id="benderLink"` attributes to buttons, not div's

**Edit:**

I see now buttons are working, but page jumps to top so what you have to do is replace:

```
...').click(function() {
```

to:

```
...').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
```

And add container for img like:

```
<div id="container">
   <img id="img" src="" />
</div>
<style> #container { height: 300px; } </style>
```

Comment: I had them in the button tags, same effect :/

Comment: I changed it for ya, it's still the same

Comment: oh sorry. add container for `<img>` so it will be `<div id="container"><img id="img" src="" /></div>`, and set container heght to positive value like `200px`. Jumping effect appears because when img pop up total page height are changing and browser is scrolling the window

Comment: should i still use prevent default?

Comment: @Axschech To be honest it's not necessary, anyway keep it - [docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/). e.preventDefault is preventing submitting forms etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found that it disappeared by changing the button type:
In Chrome at least type="submit" seems to reset the whole page when pressed whereas type="button" does not.